# Why storage fault in regex destructor?

Tags: c++, regex, destructor

I am getting a storage fault when my code destructs a regex and I am mystified as to the reason. I suspect I am missing something stupid about regex.

A little background: I am a reasonably experienced C++ developer but this is my first adventure with the regex class. My environment is a little unusual: I edit and alpha test in MS Visual C++ and then take the code to another environment. The other environment is fully Posix-compliant and just happens to be an IBM mainframe. The code works fine on Windows but fails every time on the mainframe. The problem is not something fundamental to my mixed environment: I have been working in this pair of environments in this way for years with complete C++ success.

I define the regex in the class declaration:

```
#include <regex>
...
class FilterEvalEGNX : public FilterEval
{
...
std::tr1::basic_regex<char> regexObject;
// I also tried plain regex with no difference
```

Subsequently in the class implementation I assign a pattern to the regex. The code should be more complex than this but I simplified it down to assigning a static string to eliminate any possible side effects from the way the string would be handled in real life.

```
std::tr1::regex::flag_type flags = std::tr1::regex::extended;  
// I have also tried ECMA and it made no difference
try
{
    static const char pat[] = "(ISPPROF|SPFTEMP)";
    regexObject.assign(pat, flags); 
}
catch (std::tr1::regex_error &e)
{
    // handle regex error            
}
```

That works without error. Of course, there is subsequent pattern matching code but it is not part of the problem: if I destruct the class immediately after the above code I get the storage fault.

I don't do anything to the regex in my class destructor. The rest of the class has been working for years; I am adding the regex now. I think some "external" overlay of the regex is unlikely.

Here is the traceback of the calls leading up to the fault:

```
std::tr1::_EBCDIC::_Destroy(std::tr1::_EBCDIC::_Node_base*)                                               
        +00000066  40          CRTE128N                                                     Exception 
std::tr1::_EBCDIC::basic_regex<char,std::tr1::_EBCDIC::regex                                              
        +000000C8  2022        FilterEvalEGNX.C                        Call      
std::tr1::_EBCDIC::basic_regex<char,std::tr1::_EBCDIC::regex                                              
        +0000007C  1913        FilterEvalEGNX.C                        Call      
FilterEvalEGNX::~FilterEvalEGNX()
```

The code in the vicinity of line 1913 of regex is

```
~basic_regex()                             
     {        // destroy the object     
     _Tidy();                           
     }
```

The code in the vicinity of line 2022 of regex is

```
 void _Tidy()                              
         {        // free all storage      
         if (_Rep && --_Rep->_Refs == 0)   
                 _Destroy(_Rep);           
         _Rep = 0;                         
         }
```

_Destroy() appears to be implemented in the run-time and I do not think I have the source.

Any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you create a local regex the same way on some function (create, assign, destruction)? You may have an unrelated problem that happens to corrupt the memory of your class' objects.  Or your implementation has broken regex (less likely).

Comment: `[teach-me]` You're well on your way to proper MCVE. You've got "Minimal". Now please make it "Compilable". Provide a piece of code with `main()` and some dummy class as needed. As it stand, it's hard to tell at what point `regexObject` is created/destroyed relative to `assign()`

Comment: Also, keep in mind this may be caused by unrelated memory corruption: some other code is stepping on teh core and your regex destructor crashes.

Comment: We really need MCVE. If you believe some issue with EBCDIC (which is possible, I imagine, non-ASCII stuff doesn't get that much attention) it should be reproducible in simple app with 3-liner main.

Comment: Thanks all for the super-fast responses. Will create a simple example. I don't suspect an EBCDIC issue or a broken implementation; I suspect stupid programmer tricks. I really don't think other corruption is likely, but perhaps I should. I didn't try a simpler example because I thought it was just something stupid I was doing or failing to do.

Comment: Thanks! I created a simple main with a class and new, assign, delete and it works. It's either memory corruption or some interaction between something else and regex. I really thought it was some stupid omission on my part; that's why I posted here. I thought you all would say "you have to do a .clear() before you destruct it" or "you should be doing a .init(); we're surprised it works at all" or something like that. I'm going to try introducing some guard storage around the regex and see what I learn.

Comment: I added an integer before and an integer after the regex declaration. I initialize them to 12345 and 98765 first thing in the ctor. I display them last thing in the Dtor and they have those values. I added tracing to the Dtor and all looks well. A little bit at a loss as to what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, it appears to be a bug in the C++ runtime. I tweaked my simple example and now I can duplicate the problem in a 15-line main(). I am going to run this by some peers and then report it to IBM. They actually fix this stuff! They don't just respond with "yes, you have found an issue."